# Start menu not opening from either taskbar or keyboard button [ Windows 10]

Tags: windows-10, taskbar, start-menu

I am unable to open my start menu by pressing the start button on the taskbar or keyboard. When either are pressed, the current focused program loses focus but nothing opens.

I have tried typing `sfc /scannow` into Powershell but it came back with no integrity violations.#

I tried to fix it via reinstalling all Windows programs since my Sticky Notes application was not showing or opening from the taskbar either (I have it always opened). I used 
`Get-AppXPackage -AllUsers | Foreach {Add-AppxPackage -DisableDevelopmentMode -Register "$($_.InstallLocation)\AppXManifest.xml"}` but that didn't help either.

Any ideas on fixing this? I'm on Windows 10 Version 1709 (OS Build 16299.248)

Comment: Can you run in a Powershell admin prompt: `get-wmiobject -class win32_product > apps.txt` and link the output file apps.txt from the question? Pastebin link is fine for example.  I'm wondering if you have HitmanPro installed but if not, if would be good to see what else you have.

Comment: Here is the file: https://pastebin.com/X5eY4k2Y. I don't have HitmanPro installed currently but I have Malwarebytes. I gave it a run and it did pick up two PUP.Optional.ASK files which I have now quarantined and deleted.

Comment: OK, it's just that I know that there was a similar symptom because of Hitman Pro which is now fixed in the latest Beta - https://www.wilderssecurity.com/threads/hitmanpro-alert-beta.394398/page-40.  Out of interest, when you get into this state, does it help to restart the Windows service that starts with the name: `Windows Push Notifications User Service` and then some random characters?

Comment: Apologies for the late response. The initial issue has been fixed, after deleting the PUPs and restarting, everything is back to normal, so I guess that was it.


I just had a look at that push notification service and it is stopped currently. When I try to restart it, I get an error message saying it cannot be started because it is disabled or there are no enabled devices associated with it.

Comment: Never mind actually, I see the service you were talking about, the other didn't have a string of characters. Thank you for the help.