# Start Menu wont open and Windows defender wont start

Tags: windows, windows-10, start-menu

Pressing the Windows key or clicking on the windows logo does not open the start menu suddenly on my Dell Optiplex PC running Windows 10. Also, if I try and run Windows Defender, it starts to open before closing. My first thought was a virus, however anti-malware-bytes found nothing, and there are no suspicious tasks running. I did recently use SpaceDesk's HTML5 monitor driver on the pc (https://new.spacedesk.ph/) so perhaps that is what caused the trouble? I reinstalled all the windows 10 apps in powershell and restarted, but alas nothing changed. Any ideas?

Comment: maybe something useful here: https://superuser.com/questions/1302412/start-menu-not-opening-from-either-taskbar-or-keyboard-button-windows-10

Answer (score -1):

Try the following two command as administrator in cmd.exe:

```
DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-image /Restorehealth
sfc /scannow
```

And, the windows could have some conflicts with other programs.(As you said, it could be the SpaceDesk's HTML5 monitor driver)

Try the following steps:
1. Open `Settings` (you can use `Cortana` to search the `Settings`)
2. Click `Accounts`
3. Click `sign-in options`
4. Find `Privacy`
5. Turn off the option `Use my sing-in info to automatically setting up my device after an update or restart`
6. Reboot the machine

Hope this can help you.